# Is there something similar to goto in Java?

Tags: java

I am writing code in such a way that if a criteria is met, the execution is advanced further and if not, it should resume to its previous
execution point. Can anyone help?
It looks like this

```
void main(){
    methodA();
    methodB();
}

methodA(){

    if(x==y)
    {
        //continue the execution further
    }
    else
    {
        //once again go to back the calling method (i.e) methodA() and 
        //not methodB() as compiler usually does
    }
}
```

In short: I need a similar thing as the goto keyword in C++

Comment: you can use labels but i have the feeling you are doing that wrong....

Comment: Refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Comment: Start reading java docs and practice simultaneously

Comment: Use a loop. For example, read about `while` loops in your text book or online tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to skip the `methodB()` call if `methodA()` fails or are trying to call `methodA()` again?

```
private boolean methodA() {
    boolean _success = false;



    if(x==y)
    {
       _success = true;
       //continue the execution further
    } else {
        //.....
    }

   return _success;

}
```

Then in main()

```
if (methodA()) {
    methodB();
}
```

Or if you want to call `methodA()` again in main:

```
while(!methodA()) {
//...?

} 

methodB();
```

Some References:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/TOC.html

Comment: If ,if part of method A fails and else executes I need to call the methodA again and more over MethodA and methodB has retun type of void

Comment: Change the return type of the method or move the while loop inside of methodA()

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `goto` use a loop. This way you can keep running the code in `methodA`, until the condition is met, then continue with `methodB`:

```
   void main(){
       methodA();
       methodB();
   }

   methodA(){
       while(x!=y)
       {
           // the body of methodA
       }

       //continue the execution further
   }
```

Comment: Thank you very much .But,the condition is a event which occurs on click only once. It is like a Boolean

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code, you can use.

```
public class Test{

public static void main(String[] args){

    methodA();
    methodB();
}

static void methodA(){
    int x = 2;
    int y = 4;

    repeat: while(x!=y){

        System.out.println(x + " is not equal to " + y);
        x++;

        continue repeat; // to show you how to have goto statement in Java; but it is not necessary in this case
    }

    if(x==y){
        System.out.println(x + " is equal to " + y);
    }

}

static void methodB(){

    System.out.println("I'm methodB()");
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you !!! But the problem is input is an event and it is Boolean . So X!=Y would not be valid in this case

Answer (score 0):

```
        void main(){
    methodA();
    methodB();
}

methodA(){
boolean status = true;
    if(x==y)
    {
        //continue the execution further
    }
    else
    {
    if(found == true)
    {
    while(found)
    {
        methodA();
    }
    }
    else {
    found = false;
    }
    }
}
```

This could be the recursive solution, the method calls itself if the conditions are satisfied. 
otherwise it terminates. 
Hope it helps!!